# AJAX in jQuery; Instagram and Google Maps

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am working on my hand-in assignment; we have to use the Instagram API and the Google Maps API to play with. I generate a `<select>` list with `<option>`s. I collect the Latitude and Longitude from the option, to pass into the query I use to collect Instagram data.

However, I can't seem to get any further. In index.php, I have a form with the options and the `distance` the Instagram query should use, defaulted to 1000.
In init.js, I have a jQuery selector with an `.on('change')` listening to changes in either the options or the distance. If something changes, I am calling in `updateView()`.

```
function updateView(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var option = $('option:selected'),
        title = option.html(),
        lat = option.data('lat'),
        lon = option.data('lon'),
        dist = $('#distance').val();

    updateTitle(title);
    updateImages(lat, lon, dist);
}
```

So, on every change, I am calling `updateView`, which calls `updateImages`:

```
function updateImages (lat, lon, dist) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "updateImages.php?lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + lon + "&dist=" + dist,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(){
            console.log(data);
        }
        });
}
```

If I execute updateImages.php manually with the parameters in `$_GET`, I receive a lot of data, that is working fine. However, when I want to call the PHP file via $.ajax, I am not seeing any data in the console in Chrome.

```
<?php
require_once("includes/settings.php");
$lat = (float)$_GET['lat'];
$lon = (float)$_GET['lon'];
$dist = (float)$_GET['dist'];
$IG = new Instagram(IG_CLIENT_ID, IG_CLIENT_SECRET);
$IG_data = $IG->searchMedia($lat, $lon, $dist);

header('Content-Type: application/json');
$json = json_encode($IG_data);
var_dump($json);
exit;
```

**EDIT:**
Result from the Network tab in Google Chrome Dev Tools:

[image: Printscreen form Chrome Dev Tools]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the data parameter, change your success function to:

```
success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
}
```

Comment: I did change the code to take the data-parameter, but that still does not log anything at all to the console. I will also post the updateImages.php file for convenience.

Comment: can you post the http call from your network tab in google chrome dev tools?

Comment: I have posted a print screen in OP

Comment: @user3239713 where did you post it? (what's OP?)

Comment: In the original post ;)

Comment: try removing the dataType:json in case the server doesn't return the correct type, and add error function to see if you receive any meaningful error,

Comment: error looks like this: error( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) can you paste the other parameters

Comment: I have written error like this: error: function(error){
            alert('error:' + eval(error));
        }

Comment: change it to error: function(xhr, textStatus, error) { console.log('textStatus:' + textStatus + ' error:' + error); }

Comment: Result from that function is:

textStatus:parsererror error:SyntaxError: Unexpected token s

Comment: looks like your json is not well formatted paste your response content frmo the network console

Comment: http://pastebin.com/943yV4YD

This is the result I get when I execute the PHP file with the right GET parameters.

Comment: I changed `var_dump($json)` to `echo $json` and I am getting good results now in my console!

Comment: it looks like something there is not well formatted try minimizing the response as much as possible so you can figure out which part is not correct